# Clojure case statement with classes

Tags: class, clojure, switch-statement

I want to switch on the class of a given object in order to encode it.

```
(defn encoded-msg-for [msg]
  (case (class msg)
    java.lang.Double   (encode-double msg)
    java.lang.String   (encode-str msg)
    java.lang.Long   (encode-int msg)
    java.lang.Boolean  (encode-bool msg)
    clojure.lang.PersistentArrayMap (encode-hash msg)
    clojure.lang.PersistentVector (encode-vec msg)
    nil "~"
  )
 )
```

When I call `(encoded-msg-for {})`, it returns `No matching clause: class clojure.lang.PersistentArrayMap`

What is odd is that putting the cases into a hash-map (with the classes as keys and strings as values) works perfectly well.

Also, `(= (class {}) clojure.lang.PersistentArrayMap)` is true. What comparison is happening here and how can I switch either on the class of the object itself or (better) something in its hierarchy?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I believe `case` treats the class names as literal symbols - it does not resolve them to actual classes:

```
>>> (case 'clojure.lang.PersistentArrayMap clojure.lang.PersistentArrayMap 1 17)
1

>>> (case clojure.lang.PersistentArrayMap clojure.lang.PersistentArrayMap 1 17)
17
```

This is rather unintuitive, but so it works in Clojure's `case`. Anyway, the idiomatic way is to use `defmulti` and `defmethod` instead of switching on `type`:

```
(defmulti encoded-msg class)

(defmethod encoded-msg java.util.Map [x] 5)

(defmethod encoded-msg java.lang.Double [x] 7)

>>> (encoded-msg {})
5

>>> (encoded-msg 2.0)
7
```

The dispatcher uses the `isa?` predicate which deals well with the comparisons of types, in particular it works well with Java inheritance.

If you don't want to use `defmulti`, then `condp` might replace `case` in your use case, as it properly evaluates the test-expressions. On the other hand it doesn't provide constant time dispatch.

Answer (score 9):

If you are dispatching only on the class then [protocols](http://clojure.org/protocols) might be a nice solution, because they will enable you (or your API's client) to provide implementations for other types at a later time, here is an example:

```
(defprotocol Encodable
  (encode [this]))

(extend-protocol Encodable
  java.lang.String
  (encode [this] (println "encoding string"))
  clojure.lang.PersistentVector
  (encode [this] (println "encoding vector")))
```

If you need to have finer-grained dispatch or you know extending to other types is not necessary then there might be too much boilerplate in this solution.

Answer (score 4):

If you are looking for an alternative way to achieve this, take a peek at `condp`:

```clj
(condp = (type {})
  clojure.lang.PersistentArrayMap :one
  clojure.lang.PersistentVector :many
  :unknown) ;; => :one
```